# URL rewriting-code for rewriting

Tags: php, url-rewriting

i am working for a site,which is in php.....i want to rewrite url

```
e.g www.3idiots.co.in/stories.php?id=17
```

if i want to rewrite it as

`www.3idiots.co.in/stories/17.html`

can any one tell me the code for this to write in .htaccess file.?

Comment: Not really an answer, but your website looks terrible on my laptop, with 1280x800 resolution

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using Apache with mod_rewrite.  Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/stories/([0-9]+)\.html /stories.php?id=$1
```

should do the trick.  Of course you'll need to make sure that RewriteRule is allowed in that directory.  See [this wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewritePathInfo) for more information.

Comment: You forgot one "/" after "stories":
RewriteRule ^/stories/([0-9]+)\.html /stories.php?id=$1

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite can only rewrite/redirect requested URIs and not those that are in your HTML documents. So you should first make sure, that your PHP application is printing the correct URIs, so `/stories/17.html` instead of `/stories.php?id=17`.

After that, you can use the rule suggested by José Basilio:

```
RewriteRule ^stories/([0-9]+)\.html$ stories.php?id=$1
```

Though redirecting requests of `/stories.php?id=17` externally to `/stories/17.html` and then internally back to `/stories.php?id=17` is possible, it’s not good practice as that would result in twice as many requests. But here’s the rule for that:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /stories\.php[?\s]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)id=([0-9]+)&*([^&].*)?$
RewriteRule ^stories\.php$ /stories/%3.html?%1%4 [L,R=301]
```