# Changing URL displayed in address bar

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to: URL re-writing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php)
>   [How can I keep the same url in the address bar for every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088651/how-can-i-keep-the-same-url-in-the-address-bar-for-every-page)

I am using a query string to pass information to a page but do not want the string to appear in the browser address bar.

www.mysite.co.uk?lp=catlist

is loaded but I just want the address bar to show

www.mysite.co.uk

Is there a way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, there's quite a few actually.  Have you tried searching for how do to it?  Here's a hint, rewrite rules.

Comment: can you give more details what u want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

use htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule www.mysite.co.uk www.mysite.co.uk?lp=catlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Use POST variables instead. This way no data will appear in address bar.

Comment: You can't bookmark a resource that's only accessible by POST

Comment: There were no such requirements in question.