# REST APIs use Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs) to address resources?

Tags: php, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL rewriting-code for rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806697/url-rewriting-code-for-rewriting)
>   [SEO Friendly URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002203/seo-friendly-url)

Currenly i have `login.php` in which i have function for login.I am using `http://localhost/login.php?param=x`

Now i want to call this like `http://localhost/login/paramvalue`

what should i do to achieve this as i dont know naming convention to serarch it in google.

Comment: Have a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (Apache)

Answer (score 2):

This is called URL rewriting - how you do it depends on your webserver.

In Apache, use mod_rewrite.

In IIS, use the URL Rewrite module